# MySQL Single Table Scan Update

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to accomplish a single table scan in MySQL with an UPDATE? **The following is a standard example:**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

**This is the ideal situation I'd like to happen in MySQL (But this is MsSQL):**

```
UPDATE user SET (name = 'jesse') WHERE userid ='10001'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES('jeeeeee')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sort of reversed in MySQL. You perform the insert, and if the key already exists, then update the row:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (val1,val2,val3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = val1, col2 = val2, col3 = val3;
```

This is predicated on you having a unique key for the table (which you do, right?)